# Why Get-ChildItem from network location failed

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get directory names from a network location.

This works fine: `Get-ChildItem "c:\"`

But when I try: `Get-ChildItem "\\domain\test\folder"`

I get this error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\domain\test\folder'

although this path exist and I can reach it using *Start → Run…*.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not a path, it's a *network location* - Windows Explorer understands this concept, the filesystem provider in PowerShell does not

Comment: So how can i reach this location ?

Comment: Provide a full path, like `'\\my_path\actualsharename\'`

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: You can retrieve DFS share names from `CN=Dfs-Configuration,CN=System,DC=domain,DC=tld`

Comment: can i have code example ?

Answer (score 0):

UNC paths in the form:

```
\\domain\sharename\path
```

are domain DFS (Distributed File System) Shares.

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to query Active Directory to enumerate the namespaces available at the domain root (`\\domain\`):

```
$Domain = Get-ADDomain
$SystemContainer = $Domain.SystemsContainer
$DFSDomainNamespaces = Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "msDFS-Namespacev2"' -SearchBase "CN=Dfs-Configuration,$SystemContainer"

# Construct UNC Paths for the namespace root shares:
$DFSShares = $DFSDomainNamespaces |ForEach-Object {
    '\\{0}\{1}\' -f $Domain.DNSRoot,$_.Name
}
```

`$DFSShares` now contain the full UNC paths the the namespace root shares